# How to get command line variable from command line into jupyter?

Tags: command-line, jupyter

In my jupyter notebook I can create this variable successfully in the first cell:

```
  %%system
  testvar='testing'
  echo $testvar
```

which prints out 'testing' in the output.

But when I try this in the next cell I get a keyerror:

```
  mypyvar = os.environ['testvar']
  mypyvar
```

I've also tried this:

```
  import sys
  print(sys.argv)
```

but that just prints a list that contains what appears to be kernel filepaths.

```
  /home/user/.conda/envs/new3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py', '-f', '/home/user/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/kernel-7e6e7dd7-aa10-4753-aa75-cccc36344f72.json'
```

How do I read this command line variable into jupyter?

Answer (score 0):

From an `ipython` session:

```
In [1]: testvar='testing'
In [2]: x = !echo $testvar
In [3]: x
Out[3]: ['testing']
```

This use of `!` is the same as `%system` (or at least related).

I haven't done enough OS work to know the best way to set `envon` variables.

While:

```
!env testvarvar=testing
```

it doesn't look like that variable setting extends beyond that specific process call.  It doesn't affect `environ` permantently.